# How to create order in pandas dataframe groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis

I have data dataframe where in which I want to add column which will indicate the order of the of the date for each user_id separately, so it will be like in TABLE2.

TABLE1:

```
user_id         received_at          action    
0043e1a6-52e4   2018-01-05 12:32:10  A                 
                2018-01-05 12:33:13  A                 
                2018-01-05 12:42:12  B                 
0070f782-29f4   2018-01-06 01:41:18  A                 
                2018-01-06 01:42:12  A                 
                2018-01-06 01:43:11  B                 
                2018-01-06 01:44:18  C                               
008aa58a-84a5   2018-01-06 14:22:13  A                 
                2018-01-06 14:23:18  A                 
                2018-01-06 14:24:13  A                 
                2018-01-06 14:25:18  C
```

to something like this

TABLE2:

```
user_id         received_at          action  order_n 
0043e1a6-52e4   2018-01-05 12:32:10  A       1               
                2018-01-05 12:33:13  A       2               
                2018-01-05 12:42:12  B       3               
0070f782-29f4   2018-01-06 01:41:18  A       1               
                2018-01-06 01:42:12  A       2               
                2018-01-06 01:43:11  B       3               
                2018-01-06 01:44:18  C       4                             
008aa58a-84a5   2018-01-06 14:22:13  A       1               
                2018-01-06 14:23:18  A       2               
                2018-01-06 14:24:13  A       3               
                2018-01-06 14:25:18  C       4
```

Are there are more efficient and maybe simpler solution than doing iteration for each user_id separately?

Comment: I think a few of the times in your output don't match the input `DataFrame`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Number Rows Within Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997668/pandas-number-rows-within-group)

Comment: `df['order_n'] = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1`

Comment: I fixed output example. Unfortunately solution you provided does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupby `user_id` and get the `rank` using `received_at`

```
df['count_n'] = df.groupby('user_id').received_at.apply(pd.Series.rank)
```

This doesn't require a sorting step & will assign the correct rank even if the data frame is not sorted by `received_at` within each group

if the column `user_id` is set as an index (as your sample data *seems* to indicate), you could alternative use the following instead. Although, in recent versions of pandas, grouping by named indexes also works (i.e. the above might work)

```
df.groupby(level=0).received_at.apply(pd.Series.rank)
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solution is working for this example. However, in bigger sample it provides float 'count_n' if there are two different 'action' in one 'received_at'. Adding flag solves this problem: df['count_n'] = df.groupby('user_id').received_at.apply(pd.Series.rank, **method='first'** )

Comment: @Somew, glad you were able to sort out the issue