# Pydatatable enumerate rows within each group

Tags: python, py-datatable

Given the following datatable

```
DT = dt.Frame({'A':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
               'B':['a','a','b','a','a','a'],
               })
```

I'd like to create column 'C', which numbers the rows within each group in columns A and B like this:

```
     A   B   C
 0   A   a   1
 1   A   a   2
 2   A   b   1
 3   B   a   1
 4   B   a   2
 5   B   a   3
```

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997668/pandas-number-rows-within-group) for pandas cumcount() or rank() would be options, but it does not seem to be defined for pydatatable:

```
DT = DT[:, f[:].extend({'C': cumcount()}),by(f.A,f.B)]
DT = DT[:, f[:].extend({'C': rank(f.B)}),by(f.A,f.B)]
```

a) How can I number the rows within groups?

b) Is there a comprehensive resource with all the currently available functions for pydatatable?

Comment: [pydatatable docs](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Datatable now has a [cumcount](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/cumcount.html) function in dev :

```py
DT[:, {'C':dt.cumcount() + 1}, by('A', 'B')]

   | A      B          C
   | str32  str32  int64
-- + -----  -----  -----
 0 | A      a          1
 1 | A      a          2
 2 | A      b          1
 3 | B      a          1
 4 | B      a          2
 5 | B      a          3
[6 rows x 3 columns]
```

**Old answer:**

This is a hack, in time there should be an in-built way to do cumulative count, or even take advantage of `itertools` or other performant tools within python while still being very fast :

Step 1 : Get count of columns `A` and `B` and export to list

```
result = DT[:, dt.count(), by("A","B")][:,'count'].to_list()
```

Step 2 : Use a combination of [itertools chain](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and `list comprehension` to get the cumulative counts :

```
from itertools import chain

cumcount = chain.from_iterable([i+1 for i in range(n)] for n in result[0])
```

Step 3: Assign result back to `DT`

```
DT['C'] = dt.Frame(tuple(cumcount))

print(DT)


    A       B   C
   ▪▪▪▪   ▪▪▪▪  ▪▪▪▪
0   A      a    1
1   A      a    2
2   A      b    1
3   B      a    1
4   B      a    2
5   B      a    3
6 rows × 3 columns
```